# How to retrieve user metadata from an object?

Tags: amazon-s3

How to retrieve user metadata from an object?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you looking for? [S3Object.getModifiableMetadata()](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/api/org/jets3t/service/model/S3Object.html#getModifiableMetadata())